# Change System Culture

Tags: .net, asp.net, resources

How can i change system culture that affects all pages(programmatically)?
i saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209105/asp-net-changing-a-sites-culture-programmatically) thread.

but i want to change culture in my Login page with this codes.

```
protected void btnChangeLanguage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("es");
}

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fa-IR")
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fa-IR")
```

My Culture Changed by top Code.
I checked by this code.

```
MsgBox("Current Culture is " + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.EnglishName)
```

but still our text and labels are english. (i have english resource and persian resource.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a list of all cultures, see [the documentation for the `CultureInfo` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(VS.71).aspx)

Regarding your other question, you can save a cookie with the language code as its value, and read it in the overriden `InitializeCulture` as follows:

Set the cookie with the language code as its value as soon as the user clicks the button:

```
protected void btnChangeLanguage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("language") { 
        Value="es",
        Expires=DateTime.Now.AddDays(30) /* A sample timestamp */
    });
}
```

(*Little side note*: I've appended a `_Click` to the handler's name, since it may cause a conflict with the button's name in the definition)

Read the cookie as soon as the `InitializeCulture` method is invoked during the early stages of the page's lifecycle:

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    var cookie = Request.Cookies["language"];
    if (cookie != null)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cookie.Value);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(cookie.Value);
    }
    base.InitializeCulture();
}
```

Comment: Thank you how about other question?

Comment: @shaahin You're welcome. I've updated my answer with a sample solution to your first question regarding the setting of the language

Comment: @shaahin You're welcome! The first version of the answer displayed the code correctly, but it somehow was discarded after I changed some text. Strange thing :) @abatishchev Thanks for correcting it.

Answer (score 3):

Add following line to `<system.web>` section of your web.config

```
<globalization culture="es" uiCulture="es"/>
```

Comment: Thanks.
How can i do it programmatically?

Comment: You should override method InitCulture of your Page based class.

Comment: Actually, it is InitializeCulture() method. You can save culture code after login in a session variable and than use that value during InitializeCulture(). In that way different users can have different culture.