# Change resource file reference on btn click

Tags: c#, asp.net, multilingual, resx

I am implementing a way for a user to toggle the language shown (en || es). I have the following:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Lnk_cultChange" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:mySource, cultbtn%>" OnClick="cultChange_Click" />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void cultChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName == "en")
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
        base.InitializeCulture();
    }
    else
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        base.InitializeCulture();
    }
}
```

There is a postback, but nothing appears to happen. The English resource file is still displaying and no translation is made. Is my implementation correct?

Comment: Maybe this is need to be done (change) on init of the page.

Comment: debug your code and I bet your `Page_Load` event is happening / firing  before your button click event.. do some proper `IsPostBack()` checking I would put the code on the Pre_Render or Init

Comment: Page_Load will _always_ fire before click events

Comment: you could also hook in some JavaScript code that could handle onclientClick if that's available and set it's postback property to false...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like @Umriyaev suggested you have to override the `InitializeCulture()`and use that to pull the culture after another redirection. See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10672476/2596756

Answer (score 0):

Toggle the culture on page PreInit event, if you want to toggle the culture only on click of a particular button then use code as following.

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] == "Lnk_cultChange")
        {
            if (CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName == "en")
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
                base.InitializeCulture();
            }
            else
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
                base.InitializeCulture();
            }
        }

    }

    base.OnPreInit(e);
}
```

The Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] will be the client ID of your LinkButton, Let me know if this will not work

Comment: your implementation is not working for me. Perhaps I am calling the incorrect event in onClick?

Comment: Don't use click event of button, just put the condition on page PreInit like in the above solution. if not work send me your sample solution [anubrij@live.com], i will revert you with the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Put your change lang buttons in the site master.
Add the click event handlers like following

```
protected void btnEng_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en");
    Session.Add("Lang", "en");
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
}
```

And in your pages' code behind add the following method:

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        if (Session["Lang"] != null)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Session["Lang"].ToString().Split('-')[0]);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Session["Lang"].ToString().Split('-')[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
        }
        base.InitializeCulture();
    }
```

Hope that helps