# resx file won't change after switching CurrentCulture

Tags: c#, asp.net, culture

I'm pretty newbie to asp.net. I'm trying to make a language switcher to switch current culture between "ar-SA" and "en-US". here is what I did so far :

1- I made three resx files under `App_GlobalResources` folder, one named `MyProject.Resource.ar-SA.resx` for Arabic culture and another named `MyProject.Resource.en-US.resx` for English culture.The third file is the default resx file named `MyProject.Resource.resx`

2- In the master page I'm calling this function on `Page_Load` event for each page:

```
    public void SwitchLanguage()
    {
        string pageURL = this.Request.RawUrl;
        int startInd = pageURL.IndexOf('?');
        if (startInd != -1)
             pageURL = pageURL.Remove(startInd);
        languageHyperlink.NavigateUrl = pageURL;
        // check whether the language change parameter has been passed
        var language =
            Request.QueryString["language"];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(language))
        {
            language = "en-US";
            languageHyperlink.NavigateUrl += "?language=ar-SA";
        }
        else if (language == "ar-SA")
        {
            languageHyperlink.NavigateUrl += "?language=en-US";
        }
        // having the language a thand, let us set it.
        var l_culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(language);

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = l_culture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = l_culture;
    }
```

3- In the `MasterPage.aspx` simply I'm rendering values by using the name of the default resx file like so

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal6" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:MyProject.Resource,  AWARDS%>"></asp:Literal>
```

The navigation URL looks something like this  :

`~/Pages/[PageName]?language=[ar-SA/en-US]`

Now I'm expecting that asp should retrieve the correct value for the current culture but whenever I change the culture nothing happens and it remains as is (en-US) .

Do any one have any clue what is the solution?

I been searching for a solution for this problem for 2 days now !!

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET: Changing a site's culture programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209105/asp-net-changing-a-sites-culture-programmatically)

Comment: Do you have any idea how to override InitializeCulture for all pages once, it seems that I can't override it in my master page