# Are CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture cached?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

Translations are not working properly on this page :

https://www.justlearn.dk/engelsk-laerer and other pages.

The text is sometimes on English. If you scroll down on the page, the text changes to English. The translation is working on [justlearn.com](https://www.justlearn.com), but it is not working [justlearn.dk](https://www.justlearn.dk).  The text is always Danish on the homepage. I do not understand, how it is possible.

justlearn.com and justlearn.dk are running on the same machine on Azure. The websites are translated using resx files.

My codes to change the language for .com and .dk

Startup.cs

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
 if (context.Request.Host != null && context.Request.Host.ToString() == "www.justlearn.dk")
 {
  CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("da");
  CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("da");
 } else {
  CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en");
  CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en");
 }
  await next();
}
```

Found this information.
[ASP.NET: Changing a site's culture programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209105/asp-net-changing-a-sites-culture-programmatically)

Maybe, I have to override the InitializeCulture()

Comment: Are you using threads/async? Perhaps the Context (containing the Culture) isn't being carried around

Comment: Have added the complete request

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209105/asp-net-changing-a-sites-culture-programmatically
Found this article. How can I override InitializeCulture in c# core?

Comment: You write `protected override InitializeCulture()` in you `Page`... see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.initializeculture.aspx

Comment: I cannot find 'Page'. I have 'Startup.cs', 'Program.cs' and more files.

Comment: Ah... It is mvc... i don't know then. But that article is for asp.net

Comment: I have to create class file with Page.cs and add method InitializeCulture() ?

Comment: ,,@philip No... In asp.net you have aspx files backed by a .cs file that is a subclass of the `Page` class.